# How to extract xpath from element name using Appium on iOS

Tags: ios, selenium, xpath, appium

I'd like to find a way to extract the full element's XPath by using its name.
For instance I got something like this:

```
name: Moses
type: UIAStaticText
xpath: "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAStaticText[3]"
```

Now I'd like to find the full xpath using the "Moses" name tag.

```
SeleniumHelper.GetElement("//UIAStaticText[(@name='Moses')]");
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Cheers, Pavel

Comment: What about `//UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'Moses')]`?

Comment: I am still getting the same object but it doesn't seem to contain the xpath value.

 IWebElement oElem = SeleniumHelper.GetElement("//UIAStaticText[contains(@name, 'Moses')]");
oElem.GetAttribute("xpath");

And there I fail

Comment: Can you please show the input document?

Comment: Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/DkV2fa3.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MobileElement obj1 = (MobileElement)driver.findElementByClassName("UIAStaticText");
```

Or:

```
MobileElement obj1 = (MobileElement)driver.findElementByClassName("UIAWindow");
```

Once you get the object, then:

```
Obj1.getAttribute("name");
```

If you still see the issue, please attach the screen shot with XML.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it when I'm back at the office